# How to get the raw mdx cellset back

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, ssas, mdx

The cellset that is returned in Visual Studio or SSMS is within a grid. Is there a way to examine the raw data that is returned back from the MDX query? For example, returning the data that includes the font size, the color, etc. and reading that data directly?

If so, how can I examine that in SSMS or VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS double click the result grid, it will expose you the additional porperties. In VS you can use AdoMD, any results returned from a cube will be in CellSet Class.

[image]

Comment: ok, but how is the data actually passed back? I'm assuming it comes as an xml string?

Comment: Read about CellSet Class, the data is always returned in CellSet. There is no Xml involved. I hope i am able to explain?

Comment: this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset?view=sqlserver-2016 Is there a 'friendly serialization' where you can see the data?

Comment: Yes that is it. Unfortunatly i have not come across one.